# class not found by FindClass()

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

I used JNI_CreateJavaVM() to create JVM with:

-Djava.class.path=/usr/src/buck/build/bootstrapper/bootstrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin:/usr/src/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//lib/tools.jar:...

I then used the following:

```
testingUtilClass = (*env).FindClass("org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTestingUtility");
```

Though /usr/src/hbase/hbase-server/target/hbase-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar was among the class path above, testingUtilClass was null.

I verified:

jar tvf /usr/src/hbase/hbase-server/target/hbase-server-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar | grep HBaseTestingUtility

104512 Sat Feb 11 01:53:58 UTC 2017 org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTestingUtility.class

What could be the cause ?

openjdk version "1.8.0_91"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Thanks

Comment: Could be a missing dependency. Start with looking at the actual error. It's in the environment. Use `ExceptionDescribe`, for example.

Comment: Try running this with exactly the same classpath that you use in your app, it will at least help find classpath typo: javap -cp CLASSPATH org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility